# ¿Cómo unir filas de consultas extraídas de una sentencia UNION SqlServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Tengo una consulta con una clausula UNION está por ejemplo me devuelve el registro de Id igual a 1 dos veces y está bien…pero existen tres campos `{CompanyName, Email, PhoneNuber}` y necesitó hacer una especie de Merge entre estas  dos filas, para tener un solo registro de Id igual a 1.

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
     SELECT Sc.Id, Sc.NumberId, Sc.GuestIdNumber, Sc.IdStateGuest, Cp.companyName, Cp.email, Cp.phoneNumber
         FROM   dbo.ScheduledVirtualAppointments AS Sc INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyProfile AS Cp 
ON Sc.NumberId = Cp.numberId WHERE (Sc.IdState = 1)
         UNION
         SELECT Sc.Id, Sc.NumberId, Sc.GuestIdNumber,Sc.IdStateGuest, Cp.companyName, Cp.email, Cp.phoneNumber
         FROM   dbo.ScheduledVirtualAppointments AS Sc INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyProfile AS Cp 
ON Sc.GuestIdNumber = Cp.numberId WHERE(Sc.IdState = 1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesitó combinar los registros para que me devuelva algo así:

```
Id, NumberId, GuestIdNumber, IdStateGuest, CompanyName, Email, PhoneNumber, CompanyName2, Email2, PhoneNumber2
```

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

Comment: Efrain Mejias C, se estás seguro de que el id solo repite una vez. Mi sugerencia no uses UNION. Grabe en tablas auxiliares separadas las dos QUERY. Crie index para los ID's. Haga nueva QUERY con INNER JOIN de los ID y exibindo las columnas queiras de las dos tablas. Tenga em cuenta añadir alias para la TABLA1 y  TABLA2

Comment: El Id  SI se repite, fijate en la foto...Nesecito que en una sola fila estructurar los campos como indico en la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que bastaría con un `JOIN` o `INNER JOIN`, si tienes ambas tablas, solo bastaría con identificar las columnas que se requiere de la primera tabla y las que se requiere de la segunda tabla.

Solo un detalle, en tu caso en específico, debes usar sub-consultas.

```sql
SELECT A.Id, A.NumberId, A.GuestIdNumber, A.IdStateGuest, A.CompanyName, A.email, A.phoneNumber, B.CompanyName CompanyName2, B.email Email2, B.phoneNumber PhoneNumber2
FROM (  
SELECT Sc.Id, Sc.NumberId, Sc.GuestIdNumber, Sc.IdStateGuest, Cp.companyName, Cp.email, Cp.phoneNumber
         FROM   dbo.ScheduledVirtualAppointments AS Sc INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyProfile AS Cp 
ON Sc.NumberId = Cp.numberId WHERE (Sc.IdState = 1)
         ) A JOIN (
         SELECT Sc.Id, Sc.NumberId, Sc.GuestIdNumber,Sc.IdStateGuest, Cp.companyName, Cp.email, Cp.phoneNumber
         FROM   dbo.ScheduledVirtualAppointments AS Sc INNER JOIN dbo.CompanyProfile AS Cp 
ON Sc.GuestIdNumber = Cp.numberId WHERE(Sc.IdState = 1) ) B ON A.Id = B.Id
```

> Lo probé de la misma manera solo que sin sub-querys, puedes checkarlo en este [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4b78a1209f0e60939cceda2a235f9ffd)